# Why Any in Kotlin have only 3 method, when Object in Java have 10+?

Tags: java, kotlin

From documentation, i know that `Any` class in Kotlin is:

> The root of the Kotlin class hierarchy. Every Kotlin class has [Any] as a superclass.

It looks literaly like `Object` in Java, docs saying:

> Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has Object as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class.

I know that underhood `Any` will be `Object`: I take a screens with "Decompile" options.
So I really can't understand, if `Any` is `Object` at the end, why `Any` have only three methods, when `Object` have so much more?

What was the reasone to do it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do I only have one thumb per hand? Koalas have two! And the answer is because I'm not a Koala.

Comment: It's ok, i just have this question on the job's interview, and now i want to know the answer, if it exist) 
@user, you can't use Objects method with Any, they are not available.

Comment: Which of Object's method do you want added to Any? Everyone agrees `clone()` is bad. `finalize()` has been deprecated since Java 9. Kotlin doesn't make every class an object monitor, so those 5 methods are gone, and Kotlin uses `::class` instead of `getClass()`. That's it. So which `Object` method do you feel is missing? Please state your case for why another method should be added to `Any`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many of the methods in `java.lang.Object`, specifically the `wait` and `notify` threading primitives (which have been replaced almost completely by higher-level threading tools, such as `java.util.concurrent` and Kotlin coroutines) and the presence of the protected `clone` method, are considered design mistakes by the original designers of Java as well as others.

Some references:

- https://www.artima.com/intv/bloch.html#part13 (Josh Bloch on `Cloneable` and `Object.clone()`)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/392673/what-motivates-the-design-of-the-root-object-type-in-java-and-c

The Kotlin designers decided to not propagate these mistakes into its [top type](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_type).

In addition, with the existence of extension functions, it is easy to "extend" `Any` with additional top-level functionality you may need for your own project -- for example, most of my projects contain these two methods, which allow one to do fluent casts rather than bracket-style casts:

```
inline fun <reified T> Any.cast() = this as T
inline fun <reified T> Any.safeCast() = this as? T
```

Lastly, while Kotlin's primary runtime is the JVM (and JVM-like runtimes like Android) which represent Kotlin's `Any` as the JVM's `Object` type, Kotlin does support compilation to other backends, such as JavaScript and native code. Given this, it makes even more sense for the language's top type to be as lean as possible.

Comment: I'm not sure `hashCode()` should have been on `Object` either. Using a type as a key requires some consideration.

Comment: Yeah I suspect keeping `hashCode` was a pragmatic decision made for compatibility with Java.